# Can't understand why git merge -s ours will ignore previous commits

Tags: git, git-merge

I've been reading about `git merge -s ours` strategy for a few hours. All resources I've found state that it tricks Git into ignoring commits that happened before the "fake" merge that is made using `-s ours` strategy and I can't understand why:

Suppose I have the following git history, with `master` and `feature` branches that have lots of diff between them:

```
(A)------(B)-------(C)------(D) <---[master] <---[HEAD]
 \
  \
   (E)------(F)------(G) <---[feature]
```

Now I run `git merge -s ours feature`, and the result is commit `H`:

```
(A)------(B)-------(C)------(D)--(H) <---[master] <---[HEAD]
 \                              /
  \                            /
   (E)------(F)--------------(G)   <-- [feature]
```

Then I make more commits on both branches:

```
(A)------(B)-------(C)------(D)--(H)------(K)------(L) <---[master] <---[HEAD]
 \                              /
  \                            /
   (E)------(F)--------------(G)------(I)------------(J)    <-- [feature]
```

And then, while on `master` I run `git merge feature`

Correct me if I'm wrong, at that point Git will:

1. Compute commit `G` as the `merge-base`
2. Run diff between `G` and `L`
3. Run diff between `G` and `J`
4. Make a copy of commit `G`, say `G'` and apply the above 2 diffs to commit `G'`
5. Make `L` and `J` the parents of `G'`

**Here's what I don't understand:** According to the docs the changes from commits `E` and `F` won't affect the merge, but the diff between `G` and `L` will still **reflect the changes** made in commits `E` and `F` because `G` was "born" from them, so how is it possible that the changes in these commits will not affect the merge simply because `ours` strategy was used ?

In a more extreme case, if these branches diverged more wildly and there are, say, 100 files in `feature` branch (that were introduced before `G`) and that are **not** in `master`, then **won't they still appear in the diff between `G` and `L`** during the last merge ? **Edit: I can't see why they won't appear in the diff

Comment: Note: it's not so much a "trick" as the definition of the merge strategy, which is: *make a merge commit, but in the merge commit, use the same source snapshot as in the current commit*. This makes the merge strategy really easy to write as a shell script (although it's now C code): we just use `git commit-tree -p HEAD -p $other HEAD^{tree}` to make the new "ours" merge commit. (Meanwhile knittl's edited answer has the key to why a later merge ignores the "other" branch: as far as Git can tell, the resolution of the merge was "delete their work".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the *diff* between `G` and `L` does not reflect the changes from `E` and `F`. If `I` introduced a change, it will show up in the diff, but previous changes are not contained in the diff.

As you wrote: `G` is detected as the merge base and everything else is computed from there.

Perhaps the following helps:

- `E` adds a file `e`
- `F` adds a file `f`
- `G` contains both files `e` and `f`.
- `H` contains an *identical* tree to `D`
- `I` adds a file `i`
- The diff between `G` and `I` only contains the change *after* `G`, i.e. the new file `i`. Since neither file `e` nor `f` were changed afterwards, they will not show up in the diff. As far as Git is concerned, those changes were already merged (but "resolved" as to not show up in the final result, only "our" tree is part of the result).

From Git's point of view, changes before `G` get reverted when merging with strategy `ours`. You can confirm this by diffing the two commits: `git diff G H` will show you exactly the inverse changes from `E` and `F` (or `A..G` if you will).

Comment: But since the first merge was "fake", if I added 100 files in E that means they are also a part of G - so how will they not be in the diff between G and L if they are in G but not in L?  that contradicts the definition of a diff

Comment: @caffein it's a three-way merge (ours, theirs, base). The diff `G<->L` is mostly irrelevant – what is relevant is the diff between `G<->J` and `H<->L`

Comment: But the algorithm computes diff of `G<->L`  (as well as `G<->J`)and that diff  (`G<->L`) will show the 100 files. So how will they not be in the merge ?

Comment: Actually, scratch my previous comment. `G` is indeed the merge-base, so it needs to be compared. _But_ the diff `G<->L` contains the original files, just not as added files, but as _removed_ files: from Git's point of view, the files were removed between `G->H`. You can run `git diff G H` and you should see lots of removed files :)

Comment: So the real reason previous changes (before the `ours` merge) don't affect the merge is because the merge algorithm ignores removed files ? Is that what, under the hood, lets us "trick" Git into not considering these previous changes ?

Comment: No, it does not ignore them, but rather the left side of the merge (i.e. `master`) contains the "reverse" change. When you merge with strategy `ours`, you are effectively reverting all changes of the right side of the merge (i.e. theirs; anything that happened in `E` and `F`, or more generally `A..G`)

Comment: But in the second merge, which is not "fake", these files are in commit G so why should they be considered as removed ? They should be merged into master but for some reason they don't. I can't see why ?

Comment: @caffein The files are in `G`, but when computing the merge, Git looks at the differences introduces _after_ the merge-base (=`G`), not at files present in the tree of the merge-base. Run the diff manually yourself: `git diff G L` and `git diff G J`. `G->L` will contain the revert of the changes before the `ours` merge and any changes after that, `G->J` will contain all changes after `G`. These diffs will be combined to come up with the final state.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - if the diff `G<->J` includes a change to one of the files that were reverted between `G` and `H`, that means it will be treated as a new file during the 2nd, "real", merge ?

Because (on branch feature) I could keep working on many of the files that were reverted between `G` and `H` and then how will it affect the real merge ?

Comment: @caffein In such a case you will see a conflict, because a file was changed that did not exist in the other side of the merge.

Comment: Perhaps the diff is what confuses me - does it run iteratively on all commits between `G` and `L` (i.e. not only the diff between `G` and `L` without looking on anything in between) ?

Comment: @caffein no, normally a diff is computed between two diffs directly. Consider the following (1 char represents 1 line): `abc` (G) and `axc` (L). The diff will contain `-b` and `+x`. And for the `-s ours` merge of yours, `L` never contained the changes of `E` nor `F`, so in the diff between `G` and `L`, they will appear as removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
git merge -s ours feature
```

the commit `(H)`'s tree is now a copy of `(D)`.  From `(G)` to `(H)` you see `(A)` to `(G)` being undone and `B...D` being done.

The later merge sees G as the base. `G...L` undoes A...G undone, then A...L done.  `G...J` sees the feature changes.

Those changes are merged.

The `G->H` transition contains the undoing of `A...G`, because you told it to.